# heroku root :to => 'refinery/pages#home' not work

Tags: heroku, routes

Start up page worked fine at local

http://localhost:3000 
http://localhost:3000/shop 
http://localhost:3000/refinery/pages#home

http://www.myweb.com/ not work
In Gemfile:

```
root :to => 'refinery/pages#home'
mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/shop'
mount Refinery::Core::Engine, at: Refinery::Core.mounted_path
```

Here what happened:

http://www.myweb.com/shop =========> Work

http://www.myweb.com/pages/home ===> Work

http://www.myweb.com ==============> The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

Problem here: http://www.myweb.com not work
Don't know why. Could anyone fix this 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here what I found in heroku after pushed:

Problem:

- In logs refinery searched for record with ["link_url", "/" but none
  that is the error in data not the routes.rb

So I should assumed this is a bug of refinery

```
    2016-11-19T23:47:41.062659+00:00 app[web.1]:   Refinery::Page Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "refinery_pages".* FROM "refinery_pages" WHERE "refinery_pages"."link_url" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["link_url", "/"]]
    2016-11-19T23:47:41.077929+00:00 app[web.1]:   Refinery::Page Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "refinery_pages".* FROM "refinery_pages" WHERE "refinery_pages"."menu_match" = $1  ORDER BY "refinery_pages"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["menu_match", "^/404$"]]
    2016-11-19T23:47:41.118752+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered public/404.html (1.5ms)
```

Quick Solution:

- Edit the record column "link_url" with "/"